# Guard complaints about running outside of Bundler, but only on 2nd terminal window onwards

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, bundler, spork, guard

I am following Michael Hartl's tutorial and ran this 2 blocks of code

```
$ rvm get head && rvm reload
$ chmod +x $rvm_path/hooks/after_cd_bundler

$ cd ~/rails_projects/sample_app
$ bundle install --without production --binstubs=./bundler_stubs
```

now when I run Guard on my first terminal window everything is fine, but when I open another terminal window and run the exact same command, it complaints that I am running Guard outside of Bundler. Why is that so?

Still can't post images but here is the screenshot of the 2 separate terminal windows
    [terminal 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bj9Sj.png)
    [terminal 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdwiK.png)

Thanks!
Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tests

1. `rvm current` - is the proper ruby selected
2. `echo $PATH` - first position should be path to .../bundler_stubs

## solutions

1. for both errors it might work again with `cd .` - but this might be problematic
2. you need to make sure that RVM was loaded properly, and that proper ruby was loaded in session:

   - make sure you use gnome-terminal with login session enabled: https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/gnome-terminal/
   - run `rvm get head --auto` - keep a gist of it in case
   - restart your computer - it's required in some cases
3. make sure you do not overwrite `PATH` after RVM was loaded in your RC scripts

Comment: 1. rvm current is proper. 2. echo $PATH does indeed NOT show /bundler_stubs for the offending terminal windows. **cd .** fixes it. How would it be problematic? Also ran rvm get head --auto but it does not do anything for me in this case. Is there any bad consequence of leaving it auto? How do I disable auto mode? Thanks! Ryan

Comment: the bundler hook which appends to `PATH` is a `cd` hook, most likely it's not loaded as your shell opens in the project PATH ... I have just added sourcing the after_cd hook to rvm, please `rvm get head` and try again